# Hadoop on windows: Not a valid DFS filename

Tags: windows, hadoop

**I have configured Hadoop 2.7.2 on Windows, I can see name node, data node, resource manager and node manager are running properly, problem occures when I try to run one of the map reduce program provided as example.**

Please find below the command I am running
`c:\hdp\bin\yarn jar c:\hdp\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.2.jar wordcount c:\hdp\LICENSE.txt /out`

I can see all the files are present at the desired locations. 
Please find  below the stack trace:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>c:\hdp\bin\yarn jar c:\hdp\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-map
reduce-examples-2.7.2.jar wordcount c:\hdp\LICENSE.txt /out
16/02/03 16:50:55 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0
:8032
16/02/03 16:50:56 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area /tmp
/hadoop-yarn/staging/tbhakre/.staging/job_1454492091405_0006
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pathname /c:/hdp/LICENSE.txt from hdfs://0.0
.0.0:19000/c:/hdp/LICENSE.txt is not a valid DFS filename.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getPathName(DistributedF
ileSystem.java:197)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.access$000(DistributedFi
leSystem.java:106)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFil
eSystem.java:1305)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFil
eSystem.java:1301)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkRes
olver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(Distribute
dFileSystem.java:1301)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.getFileStatus(Globber.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:252)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1674)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedL
istStatus(FileInputFormat.java:294)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(File
InputFormat.java:265)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileI
nputFormat.java:387)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.
java:301)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.jav
a:318)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitt
er.java:196)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInforma
tion.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
        at org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:87)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(Progra
mDriver.java:71)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LICENSE.txt (first argument for wordcount) should be located in HDFS, not on your local machine.

Comment: I am pretty new to Hadoop, could you please let me know how can I find location of HDFS on Windows (please note I am not using cygwin), also the set up is done on local machin.

Comment: If you didn't copy it to HDFS, it is not there. To copy a file to HDFS do "hdfs dfs -put my_file /my/hdfs/dir/"

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to copy paste files manually, it worked when I used the commands.

Answer (score 2):

if you are running everything on the same machine, you can just refer to it with a file: URL, like `file://c:/hdp/LICENSE.txt`, [maybe it's `file:/c:/hdp/LICENSE.txt`; I forget the naming logic]

Comment: `file:///c:/hdp/LICENSE.txt ` worked for  me (3 '/')